# SQL Server - Check date field between two dates in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following query the date returned is 2019-07-12 14:12:58.253

```
 SELECT MAX(fileDate) AS maxdate FROM filetable
```

This query returns the following value 2019-07-11 23:46:20.317

```
 SELECT MAX(fileDate) AS maxdate FROM filetable WHERE fileDate BETWEEN '2019-01-18' AND '2019-07-12'
```

I have tried using >= and <= instead of BETWEEN with the same results.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `2019-07-12 14:12:58.253` is not in the range `BETWEEN '2019-01-18' AND '2019-07-12'`

Comment: You must do this: `WHERE fileDate >= '2019-01-18' AND fileDate < '2019-07-13'`

Comment: Data type & format of column fileDate ?

Comment: check you data for  fileDate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'2019-07-12'` against a `datetime` will be implicitly converted to the `datetime` `2019-07-12T00:00:00.000`. For your query with the `WHERE` clause `fileDate BETWEEN '2019-01-18' AND '2019-07-12'` that means that a value like `2019-07-12T14:12:58.253` is outside of the range, as it's larger than `2019-07-12T00:00:00.000`.

The common way is to use `>=` and `<` where the value for the `<` is the day **after** the day you need. Therefore you end up with the below:

```
SELECT MAX(fileDate) AS maxdate
FROM filetable
WHERE fileDate >= '2019-01-18'
  AND fileDate < '2019-07-13';
```